# What would be the regular expression that ignores numbers with 2 consecutive even digits?

Tags: regex

```
 135 ✅
 123 ✅
1654 ✅
 684 ❌
1000 ❌
9009 ❌
```

The best thing I have reach is to make group of "odd" + "digit" or "digit" + "odd" and combine them with an optinal "digit" at the begginning or end if the length of the number is not even, but it get complicated for all the cases...

Comment: I doubt that anyone will understand your question. You need to edit to clarify. State the question precisely and add examples for illustration. You need to do that quickly as there are already two votes to close.

Comment: `[02468]{2}` matches two consecutive even numbers. Use this in a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

denoting e = even, o = odd:

- `^$`
- `^o*$`
- `^o*eo*$`
- `^o*eo+eo*$`
- `^o*eo+eo+eo*$`
- ...

which is: `^o*(e(o+e)*)?o*$`

So:

```
^[13579]*([02468]([13579]+[02468])*)?[13579]*$
```

Comment: Yeap, you found the solution for ALL cases. Thank u.

Comment: Playing with it I got a "simplified" version: '^\d?([13579]+[02468])*[13579]*$'

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
^(?!.*(00|22|44|66|88))\d+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM0W7Y/1)

This uses negative look-ahead, to check for any repeating even digits. Instead of getting fancy with back-references, I opted to just list all 5 possibilities.

Comment: this accepts `684`

Comment: Oh whoops, I misread the question as "repeated" even digits instead of "consecutive".